# Comparing string is not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Consider the following code snippet.

```
var query = (from a in db.MyEntity
                         where a.MyEntityId == id
                         select a.Team).FirstOrDefault();

string userName = userDto.UserName.Replace('.', ' ');
string[] teamArray = query.Split(new char[] { ',' });

for (int i = 0; i < teamArray.Count(); i++)
{
   if (!teamArray[i].Contains(userName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      {
         return View("Unauthorized");
      }
}
```

I have a column in a database which has `,` separated values inside it i.e.

`User 1, User 2, User 3 ...`

I do not have control on how many users that go in this column. What I'm trying to achieve is to display an `Unauthorized` page to any user that's not in that column. I get the username of the logged in person using `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1];` For testing purpose I've put my user name in the column along with another but it seems to be checking every single username and then returning me the `Unauthorized` which it shouldn't do because my username is in the column. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong please.

Below is the extension method I'm using

```
public static bool Contains(this string source, string toCheck, StringComparison comp)
{
   return source.IndexOf(toCheck, comp) >= 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but it seems to be checking every single username

Yes, that is exactly what you do here

```
string[] teamArray = query.Split(new char[] { ',' });

for (int i = 0; i < teamArray.Count(); i++)
{
   if (!teamArray[i].Contains(userName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
   {
       return View("Unauthorized");
   }
}
```

You call your `Contains` method for *every single string* in the `teamArray`. And since your `userName` will only match one (if any), all the others will return you the error.

It seems you confused two things. You want to check if *any* of the strings in `teamArray` matches `userName`:

```
string[] teamArray = query.Split(new char[] { ',' });
if (!teamArray.Contains(userName, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    return View("Unauthorized");
```

So use this `teamArray.Contains(...)` to check if `userName` is inside your `teamArray`.

Comment: So shall I create an `IEnumerable<string>`? Can you provide an example please if you don't mind

Comment: @Code your`teamArray` _is_ an `IEnumerable <string>`. just replace your `for` loop with my last code snippet.

Comment: I did what you suggested and I get the following error message `'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Contains<string>(IQueryable<string>, string, IEqualityComparer<string>)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<string>)`

Comment: @Code strange, `Enumerable.Contains<T>(this IEnumerable<T>...)` is declared in `System.Linq` namespace. Do you have this namespace in your `using` list? It's a normal linq extension.

Comment: Yes I do have it in my `using` list

Comment: @Code hm, so maybe cast it explicity like `((IEnumerable <string>)teamArray).Contains ()`

Comment: That doesn't work either. It works only if I pass just the username. if I pass `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` then I get the error as I mentioned above

Comment: @Code oh that was my erroneous first version, I edited long ago to `StringComparer` instead of `StringComparison`

Comment: I can't believe I missed that :/ oops my bad. Thanks it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

See below :

```
public static bool Contains(string source, string toCheck)
{
    var results = Array.FindAll(source.split(','), s => s.Equals(toCheck));
    if(results.Length > 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Thank you.